# Exchanging the order of integration in $ \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} dt dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

For context, this gives one way to evaluate the Fresnel sine integral at infinity. The problem I'm running into is

$$ \int_0^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert\sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2}\vert dt \right] dx$$ $$= \sqrt{\pi} \int_0^\infty \vert \sin(x^2) \vert dx$$
$$ = \infty,$$

so Fubini does not apply. However, naively switching the order *does* give the right result. Is there a nice way to justify exchanging the order?

Comment: I think it might help to put this in a bit more context. If this is from a physics course, it might be a simple lack of rigor. If however it is from a math course, there might be something else going on underneath.

Comment: @Winther There is a pretty steep (exponential) singularity at $t=0$ if you do the integral in the opposite order. I'm not sure Fubini-Tonelli applies here.

Comment: @Winther I believe I've demonstrated that the premises of Fubini-Tonelli fail.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah. I just noticed, I only focused on the $\infty$-end of the integral.

Comment: @Winther It happens. This is a very easily doable Riemann integral but horrific with Lebesgue integration. OP: you may need to interpret this simply as a Riemann integral. The Lebesgue integral fails sometimes with traditional integrals over the whole real line - this is one such case.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's just a curiousity. What is going on underneath is that we only have conditional convergence of the integral.

Comment: @Winther Yes, I know. And Tonelli's theorem implies that neither exists, since you only need to check one.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The Fresnel integrals are a famous example of a conditionally convergent integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fubini, we have
$$ \int_0^R \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} \,dt\, dx 
=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^R \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} \,dx \, dt =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(R,t) \, dt$$
where
$$ f(R,t) = \int_0^R \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} \,dx = \frac{1-(\cos(R^2) + t^2 \sin(R^2))e^{-t^2 R^2}}{2(1+t^4)} .$$
(This follows from integrating by parts twice, and solving the resulting equation.)  Hence
$$ |f(R,t)| \le \frac{2+t^2}{2(1+t^4)} ,$$
which is integrable.  Hence by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$ 
\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(R,t) \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{R\to \infty} f(R,t) \, dt .$$
Hence
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} \,dt\, dx 
=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2} \, dx \, dt$$

Comment: Should it be $2+t^2$ in the numerator?

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Thanks.  I fixed it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, the only reason we can apply Fubini's here in the first step is by knowing that the integrand $g(x,t)=\sin{(x^2)}xe^{-t^2x^2}$ is $L^1$ on $[0,R] \times (-\infty, \infty)$, correct?

Comment: @DaveNine Yes, and I used Phil Hoskin's argument in showing that.

Comment: you made a mistake somewhere ? all your steps are reversable, and at the first post we saw that the result was unbounded

Comment: @reuns In the first post, it was unbounded because he was integrating from $0$ to $\infty$.  But I am integrating from $0$ to $R$.  And in this case, the argument Phil Hoskin's used can be used to show the function is in $L^1$.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith which argument ? that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2 x^2} dt = \frac{1}{x} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2} du$ ?

Comment: $$ \int_0^R \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert\sin(x^2)x e^{-t^2 x^2}\vert dt \right] dx = \sqrt{\pi} \int_0^R \vert \sin(x^2) \vert dx  \le \sqrt\pi R.$$

Comment: so what ? I understand your steps, but when you reverse them you get a contradiction, so, there is a trick somewhere ? I'm asking where

Comment: @reuns What contradiction are you seeing?

Comment: There's no contradiction @reuns. My argument only showed the premises of Fubini's theorem failed for this double integral. That doesn't mean the conclusion is false.

Comment: @reuns Also, I only showed that the left hand integral exists in the Riemannian sense.

Comment: that the result is bounded... ok I'm bored bye. :)

Comment: @reuns In Phil Hoskin's argument, he is integrating the *absolute value* of the function.  That is what he shows is infinite.

Comment: ok ! thanks, it was nearly impossible to understand as it is, had to remark that the absolute value isn't in the title.. so everything is normal. sorry.

Comment: The question isn't about the absolute value, so there's no reason for it to be in the title.